# Why isn't apply_filter('the_content') outputting anything?

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I've tried so many combinations of php to get wordpress to output $post->post_content as formatted text (as opposed to the raw formatting that `echo $post->post_content` gives me. This combination seems to be the most promising, but it isn't outputting anything. Any ideas?

(it's this line: `<?php $content = apply_filters('the_content', $s->post_content); ?>`)

```
<?php query_posts('orderby=menu_order&order=asc&posts_per_page=-1&post_type=page&post_parent='.$post->ID); if(have_posts()) { while(have_posts()) { the_post(); ?>
    <div class="page">
        <?php
            global $wpdb;
            $subs = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent='$post->ID' AND post_type='page' AND post_status='publish'");
            if($subs) {
        ?>
        <div class="navi"></div>
        <a class="naviNext"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/navi-next.png" alt="" /></a>
        <div class="scrollable">
            <div class="items">
                <?php foreach($subs as $s) { ?>
                <div class="item">
                    <h2><?php echo $s->post_title; ?></h2>
                    <?php $content = apply_filters('the_content', $s->post_content); echo $content; ?>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } else { the_content(); } ?>
    </div>
    <?php } } wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Don't know why you're not getting any output, The EXACT same code works fine on my WP install.

Answer (score 15):

As far as I know, the function that applies the main 'formatting' to the content body is [wpautop()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop). That function should be hooked into 'the_content' by wordpress. The function does do annoying things (like mess up embed code) though and there are a lot of plugins that will unhook it from the filter stack. Try replacing your line:

```
<?php $content = apply_filters('the_content', $s->post_content); echo $content; ?>
```

with

```
<?php $content = wpautop($s->post_content); echo $content; ?>
```

If that helps then you probably have an issue of the wpautop getting unhooked somewhere.

Comment: By checking all plugins's `add_filter('the_content", ...` code, found a old 'WordPress Related Posts' plugin which using wrong syntax code. By check the plugin's website, it just support up to 4.x WordPress, now the site updated to 5.x. Deactivate the plugin solved the problem. Strange thing is that there's no error found in server log!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. It turned out there was a function in my theme, that also filtered `the content`, but had a bug in it, causing the filter to return an empty string.

So check your theme and plugins for functions that filter `the_content`. In Sublime Text 2 for example you can do a quick "find in files" with <kbd>⌘/CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to find possible culprits.

Answer (score 1):

man86,

I see you are getting the post data via $wpdb->get_results(). The thing about it is that the data is returned raw, so you need to "prepare it" before you are able to use common post functions such as the_content() (which will return the content already formatted, like you'd like it to).

How about trying this (see comments on code):

```
<?php query_posts('orderby=menu_order&order=asc&posts_per_page=-1&post_type=page&post_parent='.$post->ID); 

if(have_posts()) { while(have_posts()) { the_post(); ?>
<div class="page">
    <?php
        global $wpdb;
        $subs = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent='$post->ID' AND post_type='page' AND post_status='publish'");
        if($subs) { ?>
    <div class="navi"></div>
    <a class="naviNext"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/navi-next.png" alt="" /></a>
    <div class="scrollable">
        <div class="items">
            <?php foreach($subs as $post) { // <-- changed $s to $post
            setup_postdata($post) // <--use setup_postdata to prepare post
             ?>
            <div class="item">
                <h2><?php the_title(); // <-- use "the_title() now that the data has been prepared ?></h2>
                <?php the_content(); // <-- use "the_content() now that the data has been prepared ?>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } else { the_content(); } ?>
</div>
<?php } } wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Examples_5 ("Get all information on the Drafts by User 5")

Thanks, I hope that helps!

Vq.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `echo` the results of the `apply_filters` call:

```
<?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $s->post_content); ?>
```

Or, as you've got it coded:

```
<?php 
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $s->post_content); 
    echo $content;
?>
```

Comment: crap! Didn't notice that you were already doing that in your original example.  If you just `echo $s->post_content;` do you get the raw formatting of the post?

Comment: yes– echo $s->post_content gives me raw formatting, but echoing the filter does not.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is too basic, but it might help if you echoed the content:

```
<?php
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $s->post_content);
echo $content;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you adding the filter? You can use add_filter that specifies a function that will receive $content. You can do any filtering that you need via this function.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Create_a_Filter_Function

Comment: This looks like a step in the right direction... I'm not adding the filter anywhere, just applying it. How would I add it in this instance? Thanks!

Comment: you should be able to just add it via your theme's functions.php file

Comment: I just looked back at your original post and you could also probably use setup_postdata($s) inside you for loop and use the_content().


You can see that used here - http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Posts_list_with_offset

Answer (score 0):

hmm.. for some reason, i can get content to display when I removed the top line and bottom line.

maybe the problem is the query_posts call .. and not the apply_filters() call.

i can switch display mode depending on whether or not I use apply_filters() or not. which i believe is what you are after.

Comment: just doing <?php echo $s->post_content; ?> gives me unformatted content (the p tags and all formatting are stripped) so I am trying to use "the_content_ filter to get rich text back.

Comment: sorry, i wasn't clear.  I removed the call to query_posts().. and that solved the problem for me.  i was able to use the_content_filter with the desired result after that.  that's why i wanted to see if you can get the same results I can by modifying or removing the call to query_posts().

Comment: I initally thought that query_posts could be the issue. If removing it does fix the problem, then I think the most likely explanation is that the $post global has been filled with 'other' data, and one of the hooked filters is reading content from the global variable. Wordpress seems to do this fine, so it's probably a poorly written plugin/functions.php file at fault. Reading from the DB always causes problems. Use Wordpress's API -- it's easier, and it'll make sure necessary globals are filled and necessary filters/actions are fired.